# Advice regarding studying algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to start studying algebraic geometry. So far I have finished obviously undergrafuate algebra such as group, ring, field, galois theory,  & Commutative Algebra by Atiyah Macdonald, Little bit of algebraic topology( singular homology,  simplical homology till CW complexes) from Rotman, I want to start studying algebraic geometry. But I am scared thinking that I may not have finished all the prerequisites . It will be great if someone can tell me, if I have enough background to start algebraic geometry& which book should be most suitable for me. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Often a good approach is just to dive in and backtrack as necessary to fill in gaps in your understanding. I've heard Ravi Vakil's notes are good.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the material in Atiyah-Macdonald (i.e., you can do the exercises) you will probably be ready to go - just be ready to look up results in the Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a view towards AG*. Obviously there is Hartshorne and Vakil, but if you want an idea of the classical material the book *Undergraduate AG* by Reid might help, as with Shafarevich's *Basic AG* (I think this is particularly underrated since he also gives a gentler intro to schemes). When self-studying these things the best thing to do is shop around and do lots of exercises.

Comment: I also forgot to mention the notes of Milne (on his webpage), which are always a good resource (and will be somewhat self contained with his other notes).

Comment: Yes, I have finished all of the exercise from atiyah MacDonald actually. I've been doing for past 1 and a half years haha. I have one question, what is he difference between headstone and undergraduate AG

Comment: Depending on the type of algebraic geometry you're interested in, you may also want to cover some category theory as you go. It's not explicitly *necessary*, but when you start getting to things like Grothendieck topologies a strong background in category theory is awesome to have.

Comment: @user631697 Assuming "headstone" is a typo for "Hartshorne": classical AG was concerned with the sets defined by the vanishing of one or more polynomial equations. The yields a dictionary between ideals in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and certain kinds of closed subsets in affine $n$-space. But this dictionary is not so natural/nice, because you have to 1) impose a number of irritating hypotheses on the ideals (or rather their associated quotient rings) and 2) only work with radical ideals. And the operation of taking the radical is quite "violent" in that there are many ideals with the same radical.

Comment: @user631697 On the other hand, modern AG starts with the idea of allowing ALL rings, not just certain polynomial $k$-algebras. In addition, the $\operatorname{Spec}$ functor which you presumably know from Atiyah-Macdonald always produces a pair of non-isomorphic schemes from a pair of non-isomorphic rings, so the dictionary is much nicer. The added bonus is that this theory is much more geometrically robust: the intersection of a parabola with a tangent line is no longer just a point, it is a point with a distinguished tangent direction that "remembers" how this point arose as an intersection.

Comment: This last example (parabola $\cap$ tangent line) is precisely the kind of structure that is systematically ignored by taking the radical.

Comment: @Geoff yeah man! Definitely, I have read about category theory already while studying atiyah MacDonald. Really basic things to be honest, but I know a little

Comment: @user631697 It'll be really helpful when you learn about sheaves as well. I recommend eventually picking it up! Maybe not right away, but the more you learn the more it'll help down the line.

Comment: @user631697 A particularly good book to learn from is Francis Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Aglebra*. It's a better book to have around (if you want to understand categories of sheaves, anyway) and easier to learn from than Maclane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, in my opinion.